# Binding Silverlight Control to View Model element?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Say I have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyString}"/>

public class AlanViewModel {
  public string MyString {get; set;}
  public TextBlock Control { get; set; } //How to bind this to the TextBlock control?
}
```

Can I bind the instance of the control to the ViewModel, or must I continue to jump through hoops in the code-behind to couple them together?

I know this couples the ViewModel to the View, but it's for a good reason.

Comment: I don't think ViewModels should contain UI Controls! This might be a case where Value Converters might be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that the UI Control provides functionality that is needed the view model. Specifically converting a viewport point into a GeoLocation Coordinate. If I could do this in binding I would, but I don't see a way to do so.

Comment: Maybe you can explain that specific problem (with code snippets), which I believe should have a workaround using binding ;)

Comment: Very load alarm bell should now be going off.  "Must I continue to jump through hoops" you think that by exposing a `TextBlock` as a property in your VM that you aren't already doing backflips through hoops??  Here is my highly speculative guess, you have sacrificed simplicity on the altar of MVVM.  I suspect the view could really easily convert a viewport point to a GeoLocation but that would be break the rules, right?   Go on be a bit disobedient and have it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TextBlock}" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to know if I can bind TextBlock

Comment: Oh dear, I think I didn't think the question carefully, I now edited my answer, please see if it can help now?!

Comment: I can confirm that it works, I just tested in a test application now.